# DistributedCache/File and a single node Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Would both work in a Single node hadoop set-up? I guess it might not work in Local Mode (Standalone mode) but works in pseudo distributed mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work in pseudo distributed mode but not in local (standalone) mode.

Answer (score 0):

Distributed cache runs on both  mode i.e distributed and standalone.